# Get html from file and render in template?

Tags: twig

I have a .txt file which contains some data, but wrapped in html tags.

For example, in my text file is `<h3>Header</h3> <button>button</button>`.

I'm expecting to see a formatted header and a HTML button.
But I get plain text as `"<h3>Header</h3> <button>button</button>"`

I have created a variable in a php process file.

```
$data["imported_data"] = file_get_contents($file);
```

In my twig template I have called the variable.

```
  <div class="container">
    {{ imported_data }}
  </div>
```

The text from the file is pulled through but the html gets displated instead of formatted.
I the tried `{{ imported_data | raw }}` which didn't change anything.
Have also tried the below which didn't work.

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{ imported_data | raw }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

And also tried `htmlentities(file_get_contents($file));`
But still the html isn't formatted.

How can I get the twig template to format the html?

Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about displaying in the browser then `{{ imported_data }}` will not work because all the html stuff will be escaped.  If you view the browser source(ctrl-u) you will see a bunch of &lt; entities.  But passing the output through raw will work as you want: `{{ imported_data | raw }}`.  Your autoescape lines should also have worked (they did for me) though they are not actually needed.  If you are running in production then you might need to do a cache:clear after changing templates.  But dev should pickup changes automatically.

Comment: You may find a [recipe at the Twig site](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/recipes.html#using-different-template-sources) useful. While the discussion talks about pulling template text from a database, there should be no reason text could not be pulled from a file.

Comment: Any reason you don't put the html in your views folder and just include it from there?